# Can I mark an entire partition as "bad sectors" to prevent a device from formatting the whole thing?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, external-hard-drive

Update: My HDD did not support HPA. All well, I'll just stick to using it as a true external drive with folders for both PS3 and Xbox.

I have a large HDD that I'd like to partition and use half on my Xbox 360 (as an external drive) and half on my PS3 (as an internal drive, with an eSATA cable sticking out of my PS3) using a eSATA/USB outputting enclosure. The issue is that the PS3 will format the entire drive, regardless of partitions. In a search for a way to prevent it from formatting the second half, I noted a command [here](https://linux.die.net/man/8/hdparm) (with switch -N) which will let you change the Host Protected Area (HPA) so that the drive shows a lesser size than it actually is. Alternatively, you can use the command to just mark sectors as "bad". Would it be possible to change the HPA or mark half of it dead, let the PS3 format what it thinks is the whole drive (which is in reality the first half of the drive), then change the HPA back or mark the sectors as healthy again and make a second partition?

I know it sounds a little extreme, but at this point I'm very interested in seeing if it would work, or why the community might think it won't work.

Comment: I don't think there's many people who've done this. Why don't you just try and see if it works, and answer your own question? The worst that can happen is that data on the drive is lost, but as there's no valuable data on it in the first place ...

Comment: This sounds like a *very* bad idea.

Comment: I found that the partition table of the PS3 is custom and not standard. 

@MosheKatz, why would it be a bad idea? Lots of people use HPA to make a truly hidden partition to hide data, it's zero risk.